# C - comparing array of chars with a char

Tags: multidimensional-array, comparison, char

Disclaimer - this is some homework, so I don't want the answer, but don't have anyone to go to to get some guidance (unless I wan to wait a week, I study via correspondence).

Anyway, I am writing a little minesweeper function. The user enters the size of the grid and the number of mines. I then print out the board & the results. For example, on a 3 * 3 board with 2 mines, I would print:

```
...
*..
..*

110
*11
10*
```

The * being the mines obviously. All is pretty well, except for the results. My comparison doesn't seem to work. I am comparing chars using the == symbol, which appears a perfectly legal way to do this, but the results don't make sense to me.

I don't want the answers, just a point in the right direction. Potentially because I am comparing my array outside the bounds of the original array I set up. If this is the case, then I have no idea how to solve this problem.

My code is below. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void number1(int *stats);
void number2(int *stats);

int main(void)
{
   int n,m,i,j,k,x, rand1, rand2, counter, numMines;
   char choice;

do

{
   printf("------------\n");
   printf("lines (m) = : ");
   scanf("%d", &m);
   printf("\ncolumns (n) = : ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("\nMines = :");
   scanf("%d", &numMines);

   // check to ensure that numMines is not > n * m
   if (numMines > m * n )
   {
      printf("Error. You cann't have more mines than available spaces ");
      break;
   }

   counter = 0;
   //create minefield array

   char mineGrid[n][m];

    //set all fields in minesweeper to safe (.)

   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      {
         mineGrid[j][i] = '.';
      }
    }
    // Need to randomally make some mines for the array
    //bounds of the random numbers is defined by the values of n and m

   for (i = 0; i < numMines; i++)
   {
      //generate random number
      rand1 = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1) * n);
      rand2 = ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1) * m);
      //set as a mine:
      mineGrid[rand1][rand2] = '*';

      //Note : at the moment, mines can overlap. need to come back to fix this up.
    }
   //print out the msweeper grid
   x = 0;
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      printf("\n");
      x++;
      for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      {
         printf("%c", mineGrid[j][i]);
      }
         printf("     ");
    }

   // here is where I will print the results:
   printf("\n");
   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      for (k = 0; k < m; k++)
      {

      if (mineGrid[x+0][k+1]=='*')
         counter++;
      if (mineGrid[x+0][k-1]=='*')
         counter++;
      if (mineGrid[x+1][k+0]=='*')
         counter++;
      if (mineGrid[x+1][k-1]=='*')
         counter++;
      if(mineGrid[x+1][k+1]=='*')
         counter++;
      if (mineGrid[x-1][k+0]=='*')
         counter++;
      if (mineGrid[x-1][k-1]=='*')
         counter++;
      if(mineGrid[x-1][k+1]=='*')
         counter++;

      printf("%d", counter);
      counter = 0;
      }

   printf("\n");

   }

   printf("\n\nTry again? (y/n:) ");
   scanf("\n%s", &choice);

}while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you are using x in your array.. Shouldn't you use j? Also, is the program supposed to search for. Ones. I don't see where the user enters in a location to try.

Comment: derr. Thanks, I was using X in my notepad, so I got confused. The user isn't supposed to enter anything else, just the no. of mines. changing  the loop from j to x gives me more promising results, but still not what I was after. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As 0A0D pointed out you are using `x` where you meant to use `j`, but also you are freely adding and subtracting `1` from your coordinates, without checking if they are still within the field. That is asking for trouble.

Comment: yeah, cheers. Not sure how to solve the problem and still checking for bounds, that's my next thing to work on.

Comment: Just in debug, it seems that it's setting the counter when it's out of bounds, so I am going to have to check this somehow. Thanks

Comment: @user968127: it's a matrix.. I am sure you can find algorithms to traverse a matrix.